# jquery autocomplete not working properly in mobile

Tags: jquery, json, codeigniter, jquery-ui, autocomplete

My homepage has four autocomplete input boxes, all are working fine in desktop/Pc , but in a mobile default browser and in chrome mobile it is not display the results returned from server..

Here is my page url : http://must4you.com/beta/

MY SCRIPT :

```
$( "#market" ).autocomplete({
  source:function(request, response) {
     // alert("hello");
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://must4you.com/beta/index.php/Autocomplete/get_market_help",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            term : request.term,
            state : $("#states").val(),
            city:$("#cities").val(),
            area: $("#area").val(),
            pin:$("#pincode").val(),
        },
        success: function(data) {
          response(data);
        }
    });
  },
  minLength: 2,
});
```

In Controller

```
public function get_market_help(){
    $text = $_REQUEST['term'];
    $data = $this->M_autocomplete->get_market_suggestion($text);
    $data_suggest = array();
    foreach($data as $row){
    $data_suggest[$row->location] = trim($row->location);
    }
   // print_r($data_suggest);
    //echo "TEST HELLO";
    //
    echo json_encode($data_suggest);
}
```

**Note:** Other autocomplete has same codes but they are working fine on pc as well as on mobile

Comment: I am facing the same issue here as well.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your HTML document includes the viewport `meta` tag for proper scaling on mobile devices. Add the following meta tag in the `<head>` section of your HTML document:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```